# Extracting page text from Wikidata

Tags: wikipedia, wikidata

I might be misunderstanding the point of Wikidata, but I would like to obtain the textual content associated with this Wikipage

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Albania

which has this associated Wikidata entry https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3301000

However returning the data for this entry does not return the text found in the Wikipedia page

```js
{"entities":{"Q3301000":{"pageid":3147998,"ns":0,"title":"Q3301000","lastrevid":1097197936,"modified":"2020-01-13T11:36:19Z","type":"item","id":"Q3301000","labels":{"sq":{"language":"sq","value":"Lista e festave shqiptare"},"en":{"language":"en","value":"public holidays in Albania"},"es":{"language":"es","value":"Anexo:D\u00edas festivos en Albania"},"cs":{"language":"cs","value":"St\u00e1tn\u00ed sv\u00e1tky Alb\u00e1nie"},"th":{"language":"th","value":"\u0e27\u0e31\u0e19\u0e2b\u0e22\u0e38\u0e14\u0e43\u0e19\u0e1b\u0e23\u0e30\u0e40\u0e17\u0e28\u0e41\u0e2d\u0e25\u0e40\u0e1a\u0e40\u0e19\u0e35\u0e22"},"uk":{"language":"uk","value":"\u0421\u0432\u044f\u0442\u0430 \u0410\u043b\u0431\u0430\u043d\u0456\u0457"},"ru":{"language":"ru","value":"\u041f\u0440\u0430\u0437\u0434\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0438 \u0410\u043b\u0431\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0438"},"hy":{"language":"hy","value":"\u0531\u056c\u0562\u0561\u0576\u056b\u0561\u0575\u056b \u057f\u0578\u0576\u0565\u0580"},"az":{"language":"az","value":"Albaniya d\u00f6vl\u0259t bayramlar\u0131 v\u0259 x\u00fcsusi g\u00fcnl\u0259ri"},"be-tarask":{"language":"be-tarask","value":"\u0421\u044c\u0432\u044f\u0442\u044b \u0410\u043b\u044c\u0431\u0430\u043d\u0456\u0456"},"tr":{"language":"tr","value":"Arnavutluk'taki resmi tatiller"},"myv":{"language":"myv","value":"\u0410\u043b\u0431\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f\u043d\u044c \u041f\u043e\u043a\u0448\u0447\u0438\u0442\u044c"},"ba":{"language":"ba","value":"\u0410\u043b\u0431\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f \u0431\u0430\u0439\u0440\u0430\u043c\u0434\u0430\u0440\u044b"},"pl":{"language":"pl","value":"\u015awi\u0119ta w Albanii"},"nl":{"language":"nl","value":"feestdagen in Albani\u00eb"}},"descriptions":{"es":{"language":"es","value":"art\u00edculo de lista de Wikimedia"},"bn":{"language":"bn","value":"\u0989\u0987\u0995\u09bf\u09ae\u09bf\u09a1\u09bf\u09af\u09bc\u09be\u09b0 \u09a4\u09be\u09b2\u09bf\u0995\u09be \u09a8\u09bf\u09ac\u09a8\u09cd\u09a7"},"de-ch":{"language":"de-ch","value":"Wikimedia-Liste"},"da":{"language":"da","value":"Wikimedia liste"},"be":{"language":"be","value":"\u0441\u043f\u0456\u0441 \u0430\u0442\u044b\u043a\u0443\u043b\u0430\u045e \u0443 \u0430\u0434\u043d\u044b\u043c \u0437 \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0435\u043a\u0442\u0430\u045e \u0412\u0456\u043a\u0456\u043c\u0435\u0434\u044b\u044f"},"it":{"language":"it","value":"lista di un progetto Wikimedia"},"fi":{"language":"fi","value":"Wikimedia-luetteloartikkeli"},"oc":{"language":"oc","value":"lista d'un proj\u00e8cte Wikim\u00e8dia"},"zh-hant":{"language":"zh-hant","value":"\u7dad\u57fa\u5a92\u9ad4\u5217\u8868\u689d\u76ee"},"af":{"language":"af","value":"Wikimedia lysartikel"},"ja":{"language":"ja","value":"\u30a6\u30a3\u30ad\u30e1\u30c7\u30a3\u30a2\u306e\u4e00\u89a7\u8a18\u4e8b"},"he":{"language":"he","value":"\u05e8\u05e9\u05d9\u05de\u05ea \u05e2\u05e8\u05db\u05d9\u05dd"},"sl":{"language":"sl","value":"seznam Wikimedije"},"de":{"language":"de","value":"Wikimedia-Liste"},"sv":{"language":"sv","value":"Wikimedia-listartikel"},"zh-hans":{"language":"zh-hans","value":"\u7ef4\u57fa\u5a92\u4f53\u5217\u8868\u6761\u76ee"},"uk":{"language":"uk","value":"\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0442\u0442\u044f-\u0441\u043f\u0438\u0441\u043e\u043a \u0443 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0435\u043a\u0442\u0456 \u0412\u0456\u043a\u0456\u043c\u0435\u0434\u0456\u0430"},"zh":{"language":"zh","value":"\u7ef4\u57fa\u5a92\u4f53\u5217\u8868\u6761\u76ee"},"ar":{"language":"ar","value":"\u0642\u0627\u0626\u0645\u0629 \u0648\u064a\u0643\u064a\u0645\u064a\u062f\u064a\u0627"},"ko":{"language":"ko","value":"\uc704\ud0a4\ubbf8\ub514\uc5b4 \ubaa9\ub85d \ud56d\ubaa9"},"en-ca":{"language":"en-ca","value":"Wikimedia list article"},"ia":{"language":"ia","value":"lista de un projecto de Wikimedia"},"ca":{"language":"ca","value":"article de llista de Wikimedia"},"zh-hk":{"language":"zh-hk","value":"\u7dad\u57fa\u5a92\u9ad4\u5217\u8868\u689d\u76ee"},"ace":{"language":"ace","value":"teunul\u00e9h dapeuta Wikim\u00e8dia"},"sr":{"language":"sr","value":"\u0441\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u043a \u043d\u0430 \u0412\u0438\u043a\u0438\u043c\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0458\u0438"},"bs":{"language":"bs","value":"spisak na Wikimediji"},"eo":{"language":"eo","value":"listartikolo en Vikimedio"},"en":{"language":"en","value":"Wikimedia list article"},"nb":{"language":"nb","value":"Wikimedia-listeartikkel"},"as":{"language":"as","value":"\u09f1\u09bf\u0995\u09bf\u09aa\u09bf\u09a1\u09bf\u09af\u09bc\u09be:\u09f0\u099a\u09a8\u09be\u09b6\u09c8\u09b2\u09c0\u09f0 \u09b9\u09be\u09a4\u09aa\u09c1\u09a5\u09bf"},"lb":{"language":"lb","value":"Wikimedia-L\u00ebschtenartikel"},"ta":{"language":"ta","value":"\u0bb5\u0bbf\u0b95\u0bcd\u0b95\u0bbf\u0baa\u0bcd\u0baa\u0bc0\u0b9f\u0bbf\u0baf\u0bbe:\u0baa\u0b9f\u0bcd\u0b9f\u0bbf\u0baf\u0bb2\u0bbf\u0b9f\u0bb2\u0bcd"},"hy":{"language":"hy","value":"\u054e\u056b\u0584\u056b\u0574\u0565\u0564\u056b\u0561\u0575\u056b \u0576\u0561\u056d\u0561\u0563\u056e\u056b \u0581\u0561\u0576\u056f"},"el":{"language":"el","value":"\u03ba\u03b1\u03c4\u03ac\u03bb\u03bf\u03b3\u03bf\u03c2 \u03b5\u03b3\u03c7\u03b5\u03b9\u03c1\u03ae\u03bc\u03b1\u03c4\u03bf\u03c2 Wikimedia"},"fr":{"language":"fr","value":"liste d'un projet Wikimedia"},"zh-sg":{"language":"zh-sg","value":"\u7ef4\u57fa\u5a92\u4f53\u5217\u8868\u6761\u76ee"},"gl":{"language":"gl","value":"artigo de listas da Wikimedia"},"ru":{"language":"ru","value":"\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c\u044f-\u0441\u043f\u0438\u0441\u043e\u043a \u0432 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0435\u043a\u0442\u0435 \u0412\u0438\u043a\u0438\u043c\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0430"},"de-at":{"language":"de-at","value":"Wikimedia-Liste"},"zh-tw":{"language":"zh-tw","value":"\u7dad\u57fa\u5a92\u9ad4\u5217\u8868\u689d\u76ee"},"zh-cn":{"language":"zh-cn","value":"\u7ef4\u57fa\u5a92\u4f53\u5217\u8868\u6761\u76ee"},"pl":{"language":"pl","value":"lista w projekcie Wikimedia"},"en-gb":{"language":"en-gb","value":"Wikimedia list article"},"vi":{"language":"vi","value":"b\u00e0i vi\u1ebft danh s\u00e1ch Wikimedia"},"sco":{"language":"sco","value":"Wikimedia leet airticle"},"nl":{"language":"nl","value":"Wikimedia-lijst"},"zh-mo":{"language":"zh-mo","value":"\u7dad\u57fa\u5a92\u9ad4\u5217\u8868\u689d\u76ee"},"yi":{"language":"yi","value":"\u05d5\u05d5\u05d9\u05e7\u05d9\u05de\u05e2\u05d3\u05d9\u05e2 \u05dc\u05d9\u05e1\u05d8\u05e2"},"cs":{"language":"cs","value":"seznam na projektech Wikimedia"},"ast":{"language":"ast","value":"art\u00edculu de llista de Wikimedia"},"zh-my":{"language":"zh-my","value":"\u7ef4\u57fa\u5a92\u4f53\u5217\u8868\u6761\u76ee"},"si":{"language":"si","value":"\u0dc0\u0dd2\u0d9a\u0dd2\u0db8\u0dd3\u0da9\u0dd2\u0dba\u0dcf \u0dbd\u0dd0\u0dba\u0dd2\u0dc3\u0dca\u0dad\u0dd4 \u0dbd\u0dd2\u0db4\u0dd2\u0dba"},"sk":{"language":"sk","value":"zoznamov\u00fd \u010dl\u00e1nok projektov Wikimedia"},"hr":{"language":"hr","value":"popis na Wikimediji"},"ro":{"language":"ro","value":"articol-list\u0103 \u00een cadrul unui proiect Wikimedia"},"tr":{"language":"tr","value":"Vikimedya liste maddesi"},"eu":{"language":"eu","value":"Wikimediako zerrenda artikulua"},"tg":{"language":"tg","value":"\u0441\u0430\u04b3\u0438\u0444\u0430\u0438 \u0444\u0435\u04b3\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0442\u04e3"},"ba":{"language":"ba","value":"Wikimedia-Listn"},"mk":{"language":"mk","value":"\u0441\u043f\u0438\u0441\u043e\u043a \u043d\u0430 \u0441\u0442\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0438 \u043d\u0430 \u0412\u0438\u043a\u0438\u043c\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0458\u0430"},"th":{"language":"th","value":"\u0e1a\u0e17\u0e04\u0e27\u0e32\u0e21\u0e23\u0e32\u0e22\u0e0a\u0e37\u0e48\u0e2d\u0e27\u0e34\u0e01\u0e34\u0e21\u0e35\u0e40\u0e14\u0e35\u0e22"},"ms":{"language":"ms","value":"rencana senarai Wikimedia"},"nn":{"language":"nn","value":"Wikimedia-listeartikkel"},"sq":{"language":"sq","value":"Lista e festave n\u00eb Kosov\u00eb dhe Shqip\u00ebri"}},"aliases":{},"claims":{"P31":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P31","hash":"5ff6e63e2f39587f9d461b31cfc42484ea0330d1","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":13406463,"id":"Q13406463"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"},"type":"statement","id":"Q3301000$2C15B823-200C-482E-85C7-061CCD0E6830","rank":"normal"}],"P360":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P360","hash":"9404887c1573c4080057c5b2ee8aec47e77fc9e7","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":1197685,"id":"Q1197685"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"},"type":"statement","id":"Q3301000$3B2A0F22-7E22-413C-AEA5-AC883087D10E","rank":"normal"}]},"sitelinks":{"azwiki":{"site":"azwiki","title":"Albaniya d\u00f6vl\u0259t bayramlar\u0131 v\u0259 x\u00fcsusi g\u00fcnl\u0259ri","badges":[]},"bawiki":{"site":"bawiki","title":"\u0410\u043b\u0431\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f \u0431\u0430\u0439\u0440\u0430\u043c\u0434\u0430\u0440\u044b","badges":[]},"be_x_oldwiki":{"site":"be_x_oldwiki","title":"\u0421\u044c\u0432\u044f\u0442\u044b \u0410\u043b\u044c\u0431\u0430\u043d\u0456\u0456","badges":[]},"cswiki":{"site":"cswiki","title":"St\u00e1tn\u00ed sv\u00e1tky Alb\u00e1nie","badges":[]},"enwiki":{"site":"enwiki","title":"Public holidays in Albania","badges":[]},"eswiki":{"site":"eswiki","title":"Anexo:D\u00edas festivos en Albania","badges":[]},"hywiki":{"site":"hywiki","title":"\u0531\u056c\u0562\u0561\u0576\u056b\u0561\u0575\u056b \u057f\u0578\u0576\u0565\u0580","badges":[]},"myvwiki":{"site":"myvwiki","title":"\u0410\u043b\u0431\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f\u043d\u044c \u041f\u043e\u043a\u0448\u0447\u0438\u0442\u044c","badges":[]},"plwiki":{"site":"plwiki","title":"\u015awi\u0119ta w Albanii","badges":[]},"ruwiki":{"site":"ruwiki","title":"\u041f\u0440\u0430\u0437\u0434\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0438 \u0410\u043b\u0431\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0438","badges":[]},"sqwiki":{"site":"sqwiki","title":"Lista e festave shqiptare","badges":[]},"thwiki":{"site":"thwiki","title":"\u0e27\u0e31\u0e19\u0e2b\u0e22\u0e38\u0e14\u0e43\u0e19\u0e1b\u0e23\u0e30\u0e40\u0e17\u0e28\u0e41\u0e2d\u0e25\u0e40\u0e1a\u0e40\u0e19\u0e35\u0e22","badges":[]},"trwiki":{"site":"trwiki","title":"Arnavutluk'taki resmi tatiller","badges":[]},"ukwiki":{"site":"ukwiki","title":"\u0421\u0432\u044f\u0442\u0430 \u0410\u043b\u0431\u0430\u043d\u0456\u0457","badges":[]}}}},"success":1}
```

I know of the Wikipedia API but their licensing terms are not suitable for our use case.

Comment: the text for the wikipedia page is available under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License (regardless of whether you retrieve  that text from the API or not). it can be seen at the bottom of the wikepedia page you linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have misunderstood Wikidata - it is a collection of data in general, not data about Wikipedia articles.

Are you sure about the Wikipedia API licence? Sure you're not referring to a wrapper of some form? All Wikipedia content is free to use for any purpose: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License

This call gets you the page content: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Public_holidays_in_Albania&prop=text&format=json you'll need to process it further to extract useful information.

Comment: just a note. The license is Creative Commons with the condition of Attribution and Share Alike. You cannot use the content if you do not intent to follow these conditions.